# Right To Left Language Bracket Reversed

Tags: c#, right-to-left

I am using a StringBuilder in C# to append some text, which can be English (left to right) or Arabic (right to left)

```
stringBuilder.Append("(");
stringBuilder.Append(text);
stringBuilder.Append(") ");
stringBuilder.Append(text);
```

If text = "A", then output is "(A) A"

But if text = "بتث", then output is "(بتث) بتث"

Any ideas?

Comment: 99.999% it's not the code fault but rather whatever output you choose. Where you see this output? It's terribly complicated for UI to support both directions, to this day even gmail has major problems with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a well-known flaw in the Windows text rendering engine when asked to render Right-To-Left text, Arabic or Hebrew.  It has a difficult problem to solve, people often fall back to Western words and punctuation when there is no good alternative word available in the language.  Brand and company names for example.  The renderer tries to guess at the proper render order by looking at the code points, with characters in the Latin character set clearly having to be rendered left-to-right.

But it fumbles at punctuation, with brackets being the most visible.  You have to be explicit about it so it knows what to do, you must use the Unicode Right-to-left mark, `U+200F` or `\u200f` in C# code.  Conversely, use the Left-to-right mark if you know you need LTR rendering, `U+200E`.

Comment: Putting the right-to-left after the closing will solve this particular output issue, but if you can, you must apply the correct direction value to your control.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AppendFormat` instead of just `Append`:

```
stringBuilder.AppendFormat("({0}) {0}", text)
```

This *may* fix the issue, but it may - you need to look at the `text` value - it probably has LTR/RTL markers characters embedded. These need to either be removed or corrected in the value.

Comment: The latter part of your answer is true regarding (LTR/RTL markers), that is if `AppendFormat` is essentially `Append(string.Format("{0}", text))` (I tested `Append(string.Format(""))`)

Comment: @LukeHennerley - It essentially is that - just more convenient than multiple appends as the OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I managed to solve it by creating a function that checks each Char in Unicode. If it is from page FE then I add 202C after it as shown below. Without this it gets RTL and LTF mixed for what I wanted.

```
string us = string.Format("\uFE9E\u202C\uFE98\u202C\uFEB8\u202C\uFEC6\u202C\uFEEB\u202C\u0020\u0660\u0662\u0664\u0668 Aa1");
```