# Align Arabic String with Numeric Values

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to insert some string values to a text file. This string line includes English characters, Arabic characters and numbers.

```
Dim arabicTerm As String = "مجموع"
Dim englishTerm As String = "Total"
Dim numericVal As Decimal = 100.0
```

This will save the given text into a text file

```
WriteToText.ArabicText.WriteArabic(String.Format("{0}\{1} : {2}"
                                                 , englishTerm
                                                 , arabicTerm
                                                 , numericVal))
```

The format I need to show in the text file is,

```
englishTerm\arabicTerm : numericVal
```

But in the text file it shows like - `Total\مجموع : 100`

Can anyone please help with this.

Thank you all,
Akila

Comment: possible duplicate of [Right To Left Language Bracket Reversed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503691/right-to-left-language-bracket-reversed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the different direction in which the characters are read (english: left-to-right, arabic: right-to-left). You need to express this change in direction.

```
string RLM = ((char)0x200F).ToString();
```

Insert this between the change and it should work. [0x200F is the Unicode Right-To-Left Mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200F/index.htm)

Comment: if i want some general solution what should i do for that
like use every string right to left  in vb.net