# C# string.Format in Right To Left Language Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, right-to-left

```
string s1 = "s1";
string s2 = "s2";

string s3 = string.Format("{0} - {1}", s1, s2);
```

I want my string s3 to be `s1 - s2` in English(LTR langs) , but `s2 - s1` in Arabic(RTL langs).

I'm doing this in Xamarin, I've tried with
`string s3 = string.Format(new CultureInfo("ar-AR"),"{0} - {1}", s1, s2);`
but to no avail.

Is there something that can be done?

Comment: So you need a string.Format that inserts its parameters starting from the tail. I don't think that there is anything like that. Probably a custom made solution is needed (meaning the introduction of an if condition)

Answer (score 2):

As I have said in my comment above, I don't think that there is some kind of method or flag for string.Format that takes the parameters and inverts them as required. But perhaps in a simple case you can just create your own string extension that takes care of your case.

For example, put this code in a static class

```
public static string BidiFormat(string s, params object[] values)
{
    IEnumerable<object> data = values;
    if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft)
        data = values.Reverse();

    return string.Format(s, data.ToArray());
}
```

Now you should be able to write

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("ar-AR");
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = ci;

string s1 = "s1";
string s2 = "s2";
string fmt = "{0} - {1}";
string s3 = fmt.BidiFormat(s1, s2);
```

Comment: yeah a extension should fix that , but I thought something in-built would be better(or rather less error prone), there should be something , right? I mean , (Hello, Name ) is a classic example. in Arabic it would be Name , hello. no?

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Let's wait and see if someone comes with a better idea.

Comment: Let's hope something changed since 2013, see: [This is a well-known flaw in the Windows text rendering engine when asked to render Right-To-Left text,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14506569/724039)  